# occlusion culling test 3d

Tags: hidden, surface, culling, occlusion

Suppose we have a body,whose shell is represented by flat triangles (Polygon Mesh). The mesh is consist of millions of polygon for the needed accuracy level. Furthermore, the body is not convex (it is not a sphere, watch wiki page “Polygon mesh” for a good example of the body- the dolphin).

For a certain application I would like to know which of the polygons are seen from a certain point. I would like to emphasis the test whether a triangle is seen or not could be made to the center point, therefore, a triangle might be seen (if we see its center point) or be hidden, I am not interested in half seen polygons.

Can you recommend me a good way to do so, I would like to have the data about the polygon visibility as an output to the memory (programming variable-so I will be able to make further use with the data) and not to the screen

Comment: Have You tried anything yet?

Comment: I haven't, I am looking for an open source GPL licenced solution